# Invalid result returned with queryString on string array field elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field tags:["software engineer", "IT implementation"].

I have prepared term aggregation on tags field. which return me bucket: [{software engineer: 1} , {IT professional: 1} ]

now in term aggregation filter, I am using queryString to filter "software profess" tags. Term aggregation filter doesn't filter data.

I have used position_increment_gap:100 for tagsList field in indexing. Still, I am getting invalid result.

Comment: These multi-value fields are stored differently when compared to other fields. Can you provide sample document and query you used! and expected result?

Comment: Field data structure is like below:"                                                  
tagsList" : [
        "TESTTAGS", "FIELD OPERATIONS & CONSULTING", "INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY/SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT", "TESTTAG"]
and query is                                                                                             "query": { "query_string" : {
              "query" : "field* operation*",
              "fields" : [ "tagsList" ],
              "default_operator" : "and"
            }}    Expected output: "FIELD OPERATIONS & CONSULTING" but i am getting all value in tagsList array field.

Comment: Your query is giving correct results only. i.e when you search for single element in `array type` field if it matches then whole array will be returned.

Comment: can't we modify this query to get only search result?

Comment: No, It's not possible.